# How to convert data into json so that it can be accessed in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have fetched some data into python and I want to visualize it in google intensity maps. Here is my python code for it - (the relevant part)

```
query = "SELECT USState, NOFU2008 FROM " + TABLE_ID 
data2008 = service.query().sql(sql=query).execute()
print data2008['columns']
query = "SELECT USState, NOFU2009 FROM " + TABLE_ID 
data2009 = service.query().sql(sql=query).execute()
# print data2009
query = "SELECT USState, NOFU2010 FROM " + TABLE_ID 
data2010 = service.query().sql(sql=query).execute()


variables = {"data2008": data2008}
self.render_response('index.html', json.encode(variables))
```

I want to show a map on the browser with three buttons 2008, 2009 and 2010 with the intensity changing on the maps according to the button that was clicked. The above code gives me the following error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Yash\New folder\data\Assignments\jmankoff-byte3\main.py", line 67, in get

    self.render_response('index.html', json.encode(variables))

  File "C:\Users\Yash\New folder\data\Assignments\jmankoff-byte3\main.py", line 33, in render_response

    values.update(context)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

INFO     2014-03-03 00:15:23,483 module.py:612] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 1858
```

Note - In the above code I have only passed data2008. I also want the data2009 and data2010.

Comment: Have you tried to encode `data2008` into JSON? I think you should first do that and then encode the whole dictionary.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi - I tried that. I did variables = json.encode(data2008) and then I passed variables in self.render_response('index.html', variables). I have put a print statement which gives the following result - 
{'data2008': '[{"oranges":200,"apples":53245},{"oranges":200,"apples":28479}]'}

But in the browser console I am getting the following error - 
Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token &
And when I click on the source this is what I see -
var test = [{&#34;oranges&#34;:200,&#34;apples&#34;:53245},{&#34;oranges&#34;:200,&#34;apples&#34;:28479}]

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi - Note I assigned a dummy data in json format to data2008 for testing purpose 
data2008 = [{"apples":53245,"oranges":200},{"apples":28479,"oranges":200}]

Comment: What I meant was to try `variables = {"data2008":  json.encode(data2008)}` and then `self.render_response('index.html', json.encode(variables))`; but you passed `json.encode(data2008)` directly to the render method.